# find-command: search with created time

Tags: unix, datetime, find

How can I find things created "Jul 30 04:37" and move them to /tmp? Something wrong:

```
find .  -ctime "0037043007" -exec mv {} /tmp +
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the GNU [find](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Time) manual (and the [time input formats](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Date-input-formats) information too).

In particular, the `-newerct '30-Jul-2009 04:37'` option seems to do most of what you want.

The only snag is that the man page implies that it works for files strictly newer than the given time.  That suggests you need to use the absolute time:

```
1248957000 = 2009-07-30 05:30:00  (TZ = US/Pacific = UTC-07:00)

-newerct @1248957000
```

This still leaves the problem of how to deal with the strictly greater than semantics.

```
-newerct @1248956999 -a ! -newerct @1248957001
```

This works, but is indisputably messy (and assumes you have tools to obtain the Unix timestamp from a date/time value).

You need a new enough version of `find` for this to work (GNU findutils 4.4.2 was current in July 2009; 4.9.0 is current in November 2023).

Note that classic and POSIX `mv` expects the target directory to be the last argument.  The GNU [`mv(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mv.1.html) command has the extraordinarily useful `-t directory` option that allows you to use:

```
find … -exec mv -t /tmp {} +
```

If there were several files to move, the `mv {} /tmp +` in the question would not work, as noted by [Arkady](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1626/arkady) in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1204125/15168).

Also note that historical Unix systems and current Linux systems do not record the "birth time" of a file — but macOS does and has done for a decade or so.  The recorded times are access time ("atime"), data modification time ("mtime") and inode modification time ("ctime").  That's what you've got — "mtime" is usually the best choice, but YMMV.

Comment: I opened a new question about timestamps here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204669/easiest-way-to-generate-unix-timestamp. They are new for me.

Comment: I don't get it. In `-newerct` , the `c` stands for `inode status change time`, ie. ctime. So it doesn't seem to be creation (birth) date.

Comment: @martin: at the time when I wrote the answer, I don't think even MacOS X (as it then was) supported "birth time" in its file systems, though it now does and has done for about a decade.  AFAIK, Linux file systems still don't support a "birth time".  You can choose whether the inode change time is the value to use, but you have access time, data modification time and inode modification time to work with.

Answer (score 2):

```
for file in $(ls -lR | grep "Jul 14" | awk '{print $9}')
do
mv $file /tmp
done
```

Comment: Please, note my goal updated. I know the files, but I am unable to move them with the criterian: creation time.

Comment: *specific creating time, not smaller than or greater than.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are using the "`exec {} +`" syntax... How about this:

```
find . -ctime "0037043007" -exec mv \{} /tmp/ \;
```