# How can I generate Unix timestamps?

Tags: unix, unix-timestamp

*Related question is ["Datetime To Unix timestamp"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455554/datetime-to-unix-timestamp), but this question is more general.*

I need Unix timestamps to solve my [last question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204059/find-command-search-with-created-time/1204329#1204329) My interests are Python, Ruby and Haskell, but other approaches are welcome.

**What is the easiest way to generate Unix timestamps?**

Comment: @A.B.Carroll Can you please explain as an anwer how your online tool provides Unix timestamps? Please, attach a manual etc for it. It seems to provide a lot of data but I cannot really follow what is the target.

Comment: `gettimeofday` is the POSIX and Linux syscall name: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765301/how-do-i-get-the-unix-timestamp-in-c-as-an-int/11765379#11765379 TODO: why `strace date +%d` not call it?

Comment: If you work with, and increment time ranges (e.g. minutes, days, hours), I wrote a tool for my own use recently https://unixtime.ninja

Answer (score 704, accepted):

In Linux or MacOS you can use:

```
date +%s
```

where

- `+%s`, seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC. (GNU Coreutils 8.24 Date manual)

Example output now 1454000043.

Comment: On Solaris: 
  truss date 2>&1 | grep ^time | awk '{print $3}'

Comment: BSD date supports also +%s. Probably universal, as `date` is normally defined in POSIX.2.

Comment: @ĽubomírMlích On a SmartOS host (SunOS 5.11 joyent_20171026T003127Z), I've both `/usr/bin/date +%s and `/usr/xpg4/bin/date +%s` working. Combined with the POSIX.2 recommendation, I think this works on all Solaris too.

Comment: Note: to add 60 seconds: `date -v+60S +%s` to add 1 day: `date -v+24H +%s` and so on . . .

Comment: How to generate milliseconds upto 3 digit only ?

Comment: One liner for Fish shell users who want a `ut` command that copies to clipboard: `abbr --add ut "date +%s | xsel --clipboard"` (may have to install `xsel` package. ut = unixtime, you could also use the latter.

Comment: If you'd like to show timestamp till specific day, we can use: `date +%s -d YYYYMMDD` (Replace YYYY MM DD with year, month, and day)

Answer (score 111):

in Ruby:

```
>> Time.now.to_i
=> 1248933648
```

Comment: for rails you can use `Time.zone.now.to_i`. Though it'll give the same o/p as `Time.now.to)_i` but `Time.zone.now.to_i` is the `Rails` way.

Comment: In Rails, `./bin/rails runner "p Time.current.to_i"` is another solution.

Answer (score 22):

In Bash 5 there's a new variable:

```
echo $EPOCHSECONDS
```

Or if you want higher precision (in microseconds):

```
echo $EPOCHREALTIME
```

Comment: I think this one is the most useful of all I've seen

Comment: In case of `zsh` one may need to load the `zsh/datetime` module (https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fdatetime-Module) using the command `zmodload zsh/datetime` before being able to use these variables.

Answer (score 20):

`curl icanhazepoch.com`

Basically it's unix timestamps as a service (UTaaS)

Comment: Heh, nice. This inspired me to add a similar feature to my hobby site. `curl -L -H "Accept: application/json" unixtimesta.mp` will give you `{"datetime":"Thu, 19 Jul 2018 12:01:21 GMT","timestamp":1532001681}`

Comment: Service [offline](https://major.io/2022/07/28/extra-icanhazip-services-going-offline/) since 17th august 2022

Answer (score 19):

In python add the following lines to get a time stamp:

```
>>> import time
>>> time.time()
1335906993.995389
>>> int(time.time())
1335906993
```

Answer (score 19):

```
$ date +%s.%N
```

where (GNU Coreutils 8.24 Date manual)

- `+%s`, seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC
- `+%N`, nanoseconds (000000000..999999999) since epoch

Example output now `1454000043.704350695`. 
I noticed that BSD manual of `date` did not include precise explanation about the flag `+%s`.

Comment: Why do you include nanoseconds by `+$N`? Is it included in the UNIX timestamp in some systems?

Comment: FYI, `%N` isn't documented the man page for date in macOS 10.13.1 (High Sierra) and doesn't work. The sample output I got is: `1523342391.N`.

Comment: On macOS there's `gdate` in Homebrew https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/135749/181223

Answer (score 12):

In Perl:

```
>> time
=> 1335552733
```

Answer (score 9):

The unix 'date' command is surprisingly versatile.

```
date -j -f "%a %b %d %T %Z %Y" "`date`" "+%s"
```

Takes the output of `date`, which will be in the format defined by -f, and then prints it out (-j says don't attempt to set the date) in the form +%s, seconds since epoch.

Comment: `date: invalid option -- 'j'`

Comment: That's a GNU date extension, not in the Unix standard (POSIX).

Answer (score 7):

First of all, the Unix 'epoch' or zero-time is 1970-01-01 00:00:00Z (meaning midnight of 1st January 1970 in the Zulu or GMT or UTC time zone).  A Unix time stamp is the number of seconds since that time - not accounting for leap seconds.

Generating the current time in Perl is rather easy:

```
perl -e 'print time, "\n"'
```

Generating the time corresponding to a given date/time value is rather less easy.  Logically, you use the `strptime()` function from POSIX.  However, the Perl POSIX::strptime module (which is separate from the POSIX module) has the signature:

```
($sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year, $wday, $yday) = 
                                     POSIX::strptime("string", "Format");
```

The function `mktime` in the POSIX module has the signature:

```
mktime(sec, min, hour, mday, mon, year, wday = 0, yday = 0, isdst = 0)
```

So, if you know the format of your data, you could write a variant on:

```
perl -MPOSIX -MPOSIX::strptime -e \
    'print mktime(POSIX::strptime("2009-07-30 04:30", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")), "\n"'
```

Answer (score 5):

in [Haskell](http://danielcestari.com/2010/07/16/unix-time-on-haskell.html)

```
import Data.Time.Clock.POSIX

main :: IO ()
main = print . floor =<< getPOSIXTime
```

in [Go](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#example_Time_Round)

```
import "time"
t := time.Unix()
```

in [C](https://linux.die.net/man/2/time)

```
time(); // in time.h POSIX

// for Windows time.h
#define UNIXTIME(result)   time_t localtime; time(&localtime); struct tm* utctime = gmtime(&localtime); result = mktime(utctime);
```

in [Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25096602/get-unix-epoch-time-in-swift)

```
NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 // or Date().timeIntervalSince1970
```

Answer (score 4):

For completeness, PHP:

```
php -r 'echo time();'
```

In BASH:

```
clitime=$(php -r 'echo time();')
echo $clitime
```

Comment: for bash we already have the `date` command, so I don't think it is necessary to call php from there.

Answer (score 2):

In Haskell...

To get it back as a POSIXTime type:

```
import Data.Time.Clock.POSIX
getPOSIXTime
```

As an integer:

```
import Data.Time.Clock.POSIX
round `fmap` getPOSIXTime
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static Int32 GetTimeStamp()
    {
        try
        {
            Int32 unixTimeStamp;
            DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime zuluTime = currentTime.ToUniversalTime();
            DateTime unixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
            unixTimeStamp = (Int32)(zuluTime.Subtract(unixEpoch)).TotalSeconds;
            return unixTimeStamp;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's try [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

```
var t = Math.floor((new Date().getTime()) / 1000);
```

...or even nicer, the static approach:

```
var t = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
```

In both cases I divide by `1000` to go from seconds to millis and I use `Math.floor` to only represent whole seconds that have passed (vs. rounding, which might round up to a whole second that hasn't passed yet).

Comment: This is wrong. Both methods return `milliseconds` not seconds and unix timestamp is the number of `seconds` that have elapsed since January 1, 1970 00:00 UTC. You can use JS, just divide by 1000 and round: `Math.round(Date.now()/1000)`

Comment: @LukasLiesis must've been pre-coffee that day, I've updated my answer although I opted for `Math.floor` instead of `Math.round`.  Cheers

Answer (score 2):

If I want to print utc date time using date command I need to using -u argument with date command.

Example

```
date -u
```

Output

```
Fri Jun 14 09:00:42 UTC 2019
```

Answer (score 1):

nawk:

```
$ nawk 'BEGIN{print srand()}'
```

- Works even on old versions of Solaris and probably other UNIX systems, where '''date +%s''' isn't implemented
- Doesn't work on Linux and other distros where the posix tools have been replaced with the GNU versions (nawk -> gawk etc.)
- Pretty unintuitive but definitelly amusing :-)

Answer (score 1):

For Unix-like environment the following will work.

```
# Current UNIXTIME
unixtime() {
  datetime2unixtime "$(date -u +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')"
}

# From DateTime（%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S）to UNIXTIME
datetime2unixtime() {
  set -- "${1%% *}" "${1##* }"
  set -- "${1%%-*}" "${1#*-}" "${2%%:*}" "${2#*:}"
  set -- "$1" "${2%%-*}" "${2#*-}" "$3" "${4%%:*}" "${4#*:}"
  set -- "$1" "${2#0}" "${3#0}" "${4#0}" "${5#0}" "${6#0}"
  [ "$2" -lt 3 ] && set -- $(( $1-1 )) $(( $2+12 )) "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6"
  set -- $(( (365*$1)+($1/4)-($1/100)+($1/400) )) "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6"
  set -- "$1" $(( (306*($2+1)/10)-428 )) "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6"
  set -- $(( ($1+$2+$3-719163)*86400+$4*3600+$5*60+$6 ))
  echo "$1"
}

# From UNIXTIME to DateTime format（%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S）
unixtime2datetime() {
  set -- $(( $1%86400 )) $(( $1/86400+719468 )) 146097 36524 1461
  set -- "$1" "$2" $(( $2-(($2+2+3*$2/$3)/$5)+($2-$2/$3)/$4-(($2+1)/$3) ))
  set -- "$1" "$2" $(( $3/365 ))
  set -- "$@" $(( $2-( (365*$3)+($3/4)-($3/100)+($3/400) ) ))
  set -- "$@" $(( ($4-($4+20)/50)/30 ))
  set -- "$@" $(( 12*$3+$5+2 ))
  set -- "$1" $(( $6/12 )) $(( $6%12+1 )) $(( $4-(30*$5+3*($5+4)/5-2)+1 ))
  set -- "$2" "$3" "$4" $(( $1/3600 )) $(( $1%3600 ))
  set -- "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" $(( $5/60 )) $(( $5%60 ))
  printf "%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d\n" "$@"
}

# Examples
unixtime # => Current UNIXTIME
date +%s # Linux command

datetime2unixtime "2020-07-01 09:03:13" # => 1593594193
date -u +%s --date "2020-07-01 09:03:13" # Linux command

unixtime2datetime "1593594193" # => 2020-07-01 09:03:13
date -u --date @1593594193 +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" # Linux command
```

https://tech.io/snippet/a3dWEQY

Answer (score 0):

With NodeJS, just open a terminal and type: 
 `node -e "console.log(new Date().getTime())"` or `node -e "console.log(Date.now())"`

Answer (score 0):

In Rust:

```
use std::time::{SystemTime, UNIX_EPOCH};


fn main() {
    let now = SystemTime::now();
    println!("{}", now.duration_since(UNIX_EPOCH).unwrap().as_secs())
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need a Unix timestamp from a shell script (Bourne family: sh, ksh, bash, zsh, ...), this should work on any Unix machine as unlike the other suggestions (perl, haskell, ruby, python, GNU date), it is based on a POSIX standard command and feature.

```
PATH=`getconf PATH` awk 'BEGIN {srand();print srand()}'
```