# How facebook sharer.php capture the og:image?

Tags: php, javascript, html, facebook, facebook-opengraph

The problem is when I use different image source, it seems the facebook share page behaves in different way.

For example, if i use a image available on the internet

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.tekxon.com.pk/sites/all/themes/bluemasters/images/gallery/3.jpg"/>
```

The image is capture and show on the share page immediately, However, if I use a image on my own hosted server

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://12.22.12.34/source/test2/2012/05/07/0/3/A/Content/14/Web201205_P14_medium.jpg"/>
```

The image will not show on the first time entering the share page, but it will after I reload the page. Also, even there is no image shown on the share page, the image is still shared when I check it on my facebook . Why is that happen? Is that a bug in Facebook? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason that your second link did not worked on the first time is related to the load time of the image.

The preview images are cached so that's why it still showing you the previous image even though you removed it.

For more information of how to reload it manually check this:
[Facebook like - showing cached version og:image, way to refresh or reindex it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572441/facebook-like-showing-cached-version-ogimage-way-to-refresh-or-reindex-it)

Comment: thanks, I also noticed this problem so I append a random generate Id to the path, the share dialog should be updated everytime so it is believe not causing by caching?