# How can I use Js in order to do post Request to clear cache from Facebook sharer?

Tags: javascript, facebook, post

When i share an article from my site with Facebook sharer I have a problem with cache,
For example- if I edit the title or image of that article and share it, Facebook still share the **old content**.
I know this site:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/
but of course I need to make it **automaticlly**..
So I tried to build sometihng with JavaScript/JQuery,Like a function that get a URL and put it into this API, 
**when do I call this function? right after I press save button in my CMS** (mean that I made a change in the article).

This is the code I used and It's not working,can anyone help me with this?

```
    var url= "URL";
    function ClearSharerCache (url) {
     //https://graph.facebook.com/endpoint?key=value&access_token=app_id|app_secret
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'https://graph.facebook.com?id='+url+'&scrape=true',
                success: function(data){
                   console.log(data);
               }
        });
    }
    ClearSharerCache(url);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook like - showing cached version og:image, way to refresh or reindex it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572441/facebook-like-showing-cached-version-ogimage-way-to-refresh-or-reindex-it)

Comment: Graph API calls needs some form of client secret and access token to work.

Comment: I pased my ID and secret key like that:
https://graph.facebook.com/endpoint?key=value&access_token=app_id|app_secret
and still ERROR.

Comment: you say "error", but why do you not say WHAT error exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
<script>
function reloadLink(){
FB.api('https://graph.facebook.com/','post',  {
        id: {{URL}},
        scrape: true,
        access_token:{{ACCESSTOKEN}}
    }, function(res) {


    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you all, instead of using <script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script> I put that instead: <script src="//connect.facebook.net/pl_PL/all.js"></script>