# How do I get the unix timestamp in C as an int?

Tags: c, unix, timestamp, epoch

I would like to get the current timestamp and print it out using `fprintf`.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why it needs to specifically be an int?

Comment: @DennisMeng If I had to guess, he probably wanted to get the timestamp as the return code and cut out output-handling.

Comment: Sorry to necrobump this, but *technically* all of these answers are incorrect since `time` is **not** guaranteed to be since the Unix epoch; according to Wikipedia it can be any epoch that the vendor chooses. It also says 1900 is sometimes used. However, i would assume that it is since the Unix epoch on all even remotely sane systems.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

For 32-bit systems:

```
fprintf(stdout, "%u\n", (unsigned)time(NULL));
```

For 64-bit systems:

```
fprintf(stdout, "%lu\n", (unsigned long)time(NULL));
```

Comment: What if I wanted it in microseconds?

Comment: If you want microseconds you should use one of this function: clock_gettime with CLOCK_MONOTONIC clock id or gettimeofday. But beware gettimeofday can return decreasing time values.

Comment: so you mean, gettimeofday could return N at time T, but return N-1 at time T+1 ?

Comment: yes, because the gettimeofday is real (wall-clock) time and it may be corrected by NTP or by user.

Comment: Note that time function (and clock_gettime with CLOCK_REALTIME id) is also returns wall clock time and can return decreasing timestamps.

Comment: You can avoid type casting by specifying proper conversion specification. You can learn what `time_t` (returned by `time`) resolves to by running preprocessor on your C file (`cpp main.c`). On my 64-bit system `time_t` is `long int`, which leads to `%ld` conversion specification.

Comment: `#include <time.h>`

Answer (score 48):

Is just casting the value returned by `time()`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Timestamp: %d\n",(int)time(NULL));
    return 0;
}
```

what you want?

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 tstamp.c && ./a.out
Timestamp: 1343846167
```

To get microseconds since the epoch, from C11 on, the portable way is to use

```
int timespec_get(struct timespec *ts, int base)
```

Unfortunately, C11 is not yet available everywhere, so as of now, the closest to portable is using one of the POSIX functions `clock_gettime` or `gettimeofday` (marked obsolete in POSIX.1-2008, which recommends `clock_gettime`).

The code for both functions is nearly identical:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void) {

    struct timespec tms;

    /* The C11 way */
    /* if (! timespec_get(&tms, TIME_UTC)) { */

    /* POSIX.1-2008 way */
    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&tms)) {
        return -1;
    }
    /* seconds, multiplied with 1 million */
    int64_t micros = tms.tv_sec * 1000000;
    /* Add full microseconds */
    micros += tms.tv_nsec/1000;
    /* round up if necessary */
    if (tms.tv_nsec % 1000 >= 500) {
        ++micros;
    }
    printf("Microseconds: %"PRId64"\n",micros);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if I wanted it in microseconds?

Comment: That would mean that `int` is not the appropriate type on almost(?) all common systems. With typical `INT_MAX = 2147483647`, if you want microseconds, you can just fit a little less than 36 minutes into `int`. And of course, you generally can't use `time()` then. Portably, you'd have to use `timespec_get()` then. What is it that you want? Unix timestamp or microseconds (since epoch)?

Comment: Microseconds since epoch would be the best.

Comment: Done microseconds, unfortunately I discovered that `timespec_get` is new in C11, so portability is an issue.

Answer (score 14):

With second precision, you can print `tv_sec` field of `timeval` structure that you get from [`gettimeofday()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/gettimeofday.html) function. For example:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    printf("Seconds since Jan. 1, 1970: %ld\n", tv.tv_sec);
    return 0;
}
```

Example of compiling and running:

```
$ gcc -Wall -o test ./test.c 
$ ./test 
Seconds since Jan. 1, 1970: 1343845834
```

Note, however, that its been a while since epoch and so `long int` is used to fit a number of seconds these days.

There are also functions to print human-readable times. See [this manual page](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/3/ctime/) for details. Here goes an example using `ctime()`:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    time_t clk = time(NULL);
    printf("%s", ctime(&clk));
    return 0;
}
```

Example run & output:

```
$ gcc -Wall -o test ./test.c 
$ ./test 
Wed Aug  1 14:43:23 2012
$
```

Comment: And `gettimeofday` is the actual Linux syscall.

Answer (score 6):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
   time_t seconds;

   seconds = time(NULL);
   printf("Seconds since January 1, 1970 = %ld\n", seconds);

   return(0);
}
```

And will get similar result: 
**Seconds since January 1, 1970 = 1476107865**

Answer (score 1):

An important point is to consider if you perform tasks based on difference between 2 timestamps because you will get odd behavior if you generate it with `gettimeofday()`, and even `clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,..)` at the moment where you will set the time of your system.

To prevent such problem, use `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &tms)` instead.