# Timestamp in log files in ubuntu

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

How do I add timestamp to the log file in ubuntu?
I have the following code in my c file:

```
#define LOG_MSG(args, ...)  fprintf(log_file, "%-*d" args " \n", 5,line_count++, ##__VA_ARGS__);

#define LOG_ERR(args, ...) do {fprintf(log_file, "%-*d%s" args " \n",5, line_count++, "Error: ", ##__VA_ARGS__); increment_error_count();} while(0)
```

I tried including `date +%H:%M:%S in the above code, but it throws an error - undefined
Any help is appreciated :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: ``date +%H:%M:%S`` is *shell* syntax, not C syntax. You need to call a function which returns a string that contains the time-stamp string you want to print.

Comment: Thanks.. will try it out

Answer (score 0):

This answer is referred and checked from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765301/how-do-i-get-the-unix-timestamp-in-c-as-an-int).

```
#include <time.h>
void timestamp()
{
    time_t ltime; /* calendar time */
    ltime=time(NULL); /* get current cal time */
    printf("%s",asctime( localtime(&ltime) ) );
}
```

Hope it helps for you.