# Add 7 days to date added by user

Tags: c

I need to get input from user in string (for example 20.10.2020) and add 7 days to it. So far, I have something like that but do not know how what to do next.

This is whatI have so far:

```
   #include <stdio.h>

static int days_in_month[] = { 0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
int day, month, year;

unsigned short day_counter;

int is_leap(int y) {
    return ((y % 4 == 0 && y % 100 != 0) || y % 400 == 0);
}

void next_day()
{
    day += 1; day_counter++;
if (day > days_in_month[month]) {
    day = 1;
    month += 1;
    if (month > 12) {
        month = 1;
        year += 1;
        if (is_leap(year)) {
            days_in_month[2] = 29;
        } else {
            days_in_month[2] = 28;
        }
    }
}
}

void set_date(int d, int m, int y) 
{
m < 1 ? m = 1 : 0;
m > 12 ? m = 12 : 0;
d < 1 ? d = 1 : 0;
d > days_in_month[m] ? d = days_in_month[m] : 0;
if (is_leap(y)){
    days_in_month[2] = 29;
} else {
    days_in_month[2] = 28;
}
day = d;
month = m;
year = y;
}

void skip_days(int x)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<x;i++) next_day();
}

void print_date()
{
    printf (" %d.%d.%d\n", day, month, year);
}

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
    int i;

    set_date(5, 2, 1980);

    skip_days(7);
    day_counter = 0;

    print_date();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code in `set_date()` does not do what you think it does.  The first line sometimes sets `m`.  The `: 0` bit is pointless.  Use `if` statements.  The ternary conditional operator has uses.  This is not one of them.

Comment: An array called `daysInMonth` that has 13 entries, the first of which is zero is enough to make me run away. But not before saying I immediately thought of adding the equivalent of 7 days to the unix timestamp for the given time. Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765301/how-do-i-get-the-unix-timestamp-in-c-as-an-int

Comment: With any calculations related to time, convert to a reasonable format.  Once you have the epoch time, calculations are trivial.

Comment: time_t a;
struct tm b;

// Fill b with user's date.
b.tm_year = 2021;
b.tm_mon = 2;

a = mktime(&b);. // Transform b in seconds since epoch

a += (7 * 24 * 3600);  // Add 7 days

strftime(...);


strftime() converts the date and time information from a given calendar time to a null-terminated multibyte character string str according to format string format.

strftime() is the sprintf() function for date and time.

Remove the comments to compile the code.

Comment: Make your life easier - use the epoch -https://www.epochconverter.com/programming/c

Answer (score 1):

You needn't reinvent the wheel. A very good suggestion in the comments is to use the standard functions `mktime` and `strftime`, although the given snippet might leave some members of the `tm` structure uninitialized and distort the result, and although it is for your purpose not necessary to bother with the *epoch*. When we use

```
struct tm
{
    …
    int tm_mday;    // day of the month — [1, 31]
    int tm_mon;     // months since January — [0, 11]
    int tm_year;    // years since 1900
    …
}
```

we can take advantage of the circumstance that *the original values of these components are not restricted to the ranges indicated above. On successful completion, the values are forced to the ranges indicated above.* This means `mktime` takes care of overflows into the next month or year. So, your whole program can be reduced to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int d, m, y;
    // get date input from user on the command line
    if (argc < 2 || sscanf(argv[1], "%d.%d.%d", &d, &m, &y) < 3) return 1;
    // put that into the time structure, adding 7 days
    struct tm date = { .tm_mday = d+7, .tm_mon = m-1, .tm_year = y-1900 };
    // force to the ranges
    mktime(&date);

    char s[11];
    strftime(s, sizeof s, "%d.%m.%Y", &date);
    puts(s);
}
```

Comment: Minor No need to be stingy with `char s[11];`.  Could use `char s[3+3+11+1];` to handle `year` of any `int`.

Comment: You're right, I could well afford this and avoid the Y10k problem. :-)