# Get Unix Epoch Time in Swift

Tags: time, swift

How do you get the seconds from epoch in Swift?

Comment: Same as in Objective-C - use NSDate.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/timeIntervalSince1970

Comment: Care to explain the downvotes?

Comment: Asking for code, not looking to learn, particularly your previous comment WRT "easy SO ".

Comment: I'm looking to learn the code. Which is why I'm asking for it. This question has an upvote of 106 and asks the exact same question, just in C# instead of Swift: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883576/how-do-you-convert-epoch-time-in-c

Comment: Looks like I'm going to need moderator.

Comment: Moderator, why? Because your question was down voted?

Comment: Because the people who are downvoting it (at least you) don't believe SO should have consistent standards. So your vote is apparently based on random haphazard standards.

Comment: If this question is so easy to answer, why wouldn't someone just answer it?

Comment: Actually @Martin did answer the question in a comment above.

Comment: No, Martin linked to a gigantic reference page. More helpful than your contributions but still doesn't answer the question. See Yannik's answer below as an example of what an answer looks like.

Comment: No, it links directly to the entry for the Swift method: `- timeIntervalSince1970`.

Comment: Actually I linked to the specific method :)

Comment: Apple's website formatting didn't make that clear. While I appreciate it, it still isn't as clear as the way Yannik answered, especially for someone learning a new language.

Comment: In Sumit Oberoi's response (based on CHIP-love-NY comment)... 1000 millisecond = 1 seconds. You should divide by 1000 to get seconds. Should be: In seconds:Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 / 1000)

Answer (score 203, accepted):

You can simply use Date's `timeIntervalSince1970` function.

```
let timeInterval = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
```

You often want an Int:

```
let secondsStamp = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
```

The result is in **seconds**.  (**Not** milliseconds, picoseconds, etc.)

"Unix time" aka "unix time stamp" is explained in detail [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Note that an iOS `TimeInterval` is indeed in **seconds**.

Comment: Note this needs to have Foundation imported.

Comment: how about without using Foundation?

Comment: If you don't want to use foundation then you could use AFNetworking/AlamoFire (https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) to load https://currentmillis.com/ and then parse the html of the page. Note that you have to account for networking delays and check for connectivity. I decided to just use Foundation...

Comment: How about as an int?

Comment: It gives time with decimal.

Comment: And if you want milliseconds since 1970: `let timeInterval = Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970*1000)`. Casting as an `Int` is optional.

Answer (score 104):

For Swift 3.0

```
Date().timeIntervalSince1970
```

Comment: Good one.  Also, folks may be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39811352/swift-3-date-vs-nsdate

Comment: @CHiP-love-NY: That is not true. [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is the number of **seconds** since 1 January 1970, UTC.

Comment: It returns a [TimeInterval](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timeinterval), which is in secods

Answer (score 14):

You can get that using following

```
Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
```

This is for current date, if you want to get for a given date

```
Int(myDate.timeIntervalSince1970)
```

If you want to convert back from UNIX time epoch to Swift Date time, you can use following

```
let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: unixtEpochTime)
```

Answer (score 12):

**1 second = 1,000 milliseconds

1 second = 1,000,000 microseconds**

Swift's `timeIntervalSince1970` returns seconds with what's documented as "sub-millisecond" precision, which I've observed to mean usually microseconds but sometimes one scale (one digit to the right of the decimal) less or more. When it returns a scale of 5 (5 digits after the decimal), I assume Swift couldn't produce 6 scales of precision, and when it returns a scale of 7, that extra digit can be truncated because it's beyond microsecond precision. Therefore:

```
let secondPrecision = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970) // definitely precise
let millisecondPrecision = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1_000) // definitely precise
let microsecondPrecision = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1_000_000) // most-likely precise
```

**All that said, millisecond-precision is the true Unix timestamp and the one that, I think, everyone should use.** If you're working with an API or a framework that uses the Unix timestamp, most likely it will be millisecond-precise. Therefore, for a true Unix timestamp in Swift:

```
typealias UnixTimestamp = Int

extension Date {
    /// Date to Unix timestamp.
    var unixTimestamp: UnixTimestamp {
        return UnixTimestamp(self.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1_000) // millisecond precision
    }
}

extension UnixTimestamp {
    /// Unix timestamp to date.
    var date: Date {
        return Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(self / 1_000)) // must take a millisecond-precise Unix timestamp
    }
}

let unixTimestamp = Date().unixTimestamp
let date = unixTimestamp.date
```

*Note that in the year 2038, 32-bit numbers won't be usable for the Unix timestamp, they'll have to be 64-bit, but Swift will handle that for us automatically so we can safely use `Int` (and need not use `Int64` explicitly).*

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to import Foundation, i.e. for Linux use etc, you can use the following from CoreFoundation:

```
import CoreFoundation

let timestamp = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() + kCFAbsoluteTimeIntervalSince1970
```

Comment: Do you know when things might Date and friends will become cross-platform?

Comment: @ZoltánMatók I've heard they have plans to reimplement more of Foundation in the open. Take a look at forums.swift.org for more info.