# How do I translate a UNIX epoch to ISO 8601 in swift?

Tags: swift, epoch

I see people asking how to convert an ISO 8601 string to NSDate in Swift, but I need the exact opposite.

I understand how to get the epoch using 'timeIntervalSince1970' ([Get Unix Epoch Time in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25096602/get-unix-epoch-time-in-swift)) which returns something like '1427058740.08374', but how do I convert that to ISO 8601?

Desired string: `2015-03-22T20:51:41+00:00`

Comment: Did you have a look at NSDateFormatter, the ["Data Formatting Guide"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html) and http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
extension NSDate {
    var formattedISO8601: String {
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:SSxxxxx"   //+00:00
        return formatter.stringFromDate(self)
    }
}

NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1427058740.08374).formattedISO8601   // "2015-03-22T09:12:08+00:00"
```

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 5

If you're targeting iOS 11.0+ / macOS 10.13+, you simply use `ISO8601DateFormatter` with the `withInternetDateTime` option, like so:

```
let unixTime = 1583358247

let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(unixTime))
let iso8601DateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
iso8601DateFormatter.formatOptions = [.withInternetDateTime]
let string = iso8601DateFormatter.string(from: date)

// string looks like "2020-03-04T21:44:07Z"
```

Answer (score 0):

@LeoDabus's wonderful answer in Swift 4:

```
extension NSDate {
    var formattedISO8601: String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0) as TimeZone!
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:SSxxxxx"   //+00:00
        return formatter.string(from: self as Date)
    }
}
```

And to use it:

```
NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1427058740.08374).formattedISO8601   // "2015-03-22T09:12:08+00:00"
```