# Unexpected behavior of FireStore listener

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on an iOS app using Firebase as backend. I am encountering a problem where a listener on a sub collection is behaving unexpectedly. Let me explain my data models first:
I have a top-level collection called "families". Within this collection, I have a sub-collection called "chores". It looks something like this:

[image: families collection and chores subcollection]

Within my iOS app, I am adding a listener to this "chores" sub collection like this:

```
func readChoreCollection(_ familyId: String) {
    if familyChoresListener == nil {
        let choreCollection = database.collection("families").document(familyId).collection("chores")
        familyChoresListener = choreCollection.order(by: "created")
            .addSnapshotListener(includeMetadataChanges: false) { [weak self] querySnapshot, error in
                print("\(#fileID) \(#function): \(choreCollection.path)")
                guard let querySnapshot = querySnapshot else {
                    print("\(#fileID) \(#function): Error fetching documents: \(error!)")
                    return
                }
                let chores: [Chore] = querySnapshot.documents
                    .compactMap { document in
                        do {
                            return try document.data(as: Chore.self)
                        } catch {
                            print("\(#fileID) \(#function): error")
                            return nil
                        }
                    }
                if chores.isEmpty {
                    print("\(#fileID) \(#function): received empty list, publishing nil...")
                    self?.familyChoresPublisher.send(nil)
                } else {
                    print("\(#fileID) \(#function): received chores data, publishing ... \(querySnapshot.metadata.hasPendingWrites)")
                    self?.familyChoresPublisher.send(chores)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

According to the Firestore doc:
The snapshot handler will receive a new query snapshot every time the query results change (that is, when a document is added, removed, or modified
So, when I add a new document to the "chores" sub-collection, the listener did trigger, that is expected. However, it is triggered twice, one from local change, and one from remote change. As shown in the log below:

```
ChoreReward/ChoreRepository.swift readChoreCollection(_:): received chores data, publishing ... true
ChoreReward/ChoreService.swift addSubscription(): received and cached a non-nil chore list
ChoreReward/ChoreRepository.swift readChoreCollection(_:): families/tgO0B4bjq8uwAzmBaOtL/chores
ChoreReward/ChoreRepository.swift readChoreCollection(_:): received chores data, publishing ... false
ChoreReward/ChoreService.swift addSubscription(): received and cached a non-nil chore list
```

You can see that the listener is called twice, one with `hasPendingWrites = true` and one with `hasPendingWrites = false`. So the documentation did mentioned that the local changes will fire-off the callback to listener first before sending data back to Firestore. So this behavior is kinda expected??? On my other listeners (document listeners) within the app, they are only getting called once by the remote changes, not twice. Maybe there is a different in behavior of document vs. collection/query listener? Can anybody verify this difference?

Comment: Is there a Firestore timestamp field cotained in these snapshots?

Comment: @fakegirlfriends yes, there is. Both are populated by my client-side and not server timestamp.

Comment: But are they Firestore timestamps or your own timestamp (i.e. 64-bit integer)? Because Firestore timestamps will cause the snapshot listeners to fire twice since they are tokens.

Comment: They are Firestore timestamps indeed. That would make sense. I thought that as long as I am not using `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` it should be fine, since the the swift JSONEncoder will just encode a Swift Date object to a Firestore Timestamp, and not relying on the server to populate that field. So I guess to avoid the double callbacks, I will have to rely on the `metadata.hasPendingWrite`

Comment: Firestore converts between native Swift `Date` and its own timestamp behind the scene as a convenience on the client, but they are still handled as tokens between the client and the server, which requires a second call for token redemption. Personally, I prefer using a Unix timestamp (`Int64`) to the Firestore timestamp anyway for a number of reasons, one of which was the double snapshot return which I found annoying.

Comment: So for example, in your Firebase document you will have a field like `"created": 1529704800000 (Int)`?

Comment: Correct. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61147407/9086770