# -ctime unix command in windows

Tags: windows, unix

I have windows machine on which I need to query all the files created before x time.
In unix, we can do it by find -ctime. By specifying the minutes, I can view all the files in a certain time period.

How can I do this in Windows?

Answer (score 1):

specificaly for "creation time", installing cygwin and using find command seems to be only way I could find :-)

[find-command: search with created time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204059/find-command-search-with-created-time)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command "forfiles"
See:
http://www.windows-commandline.com/find-files-based-on-modified-time/

Comment: I can find files by days using this command.
How can I do with time ? like hours or minutes?

Comment: According to the [documention](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551.aspx), you cannot use hours or minutes.

Comment: Very limited and kind of stupid command. Check out the `/D` option: If you want to find files changed more than 3 days before, `/D -3` will do the job. But if you're looking for files changed less than 3 days ago, you're on your own, because `/D +3` will look for files changed more than 3 days *in the future* ‍♂️, of which obviously there will be none as long as timestamps aren't manipulated. Who came up with such genius?